# Apollo MockedProvider: “Failed to match x mocks for this query” where x is off by 1. Never sees the query I ask for

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I’m experiencing the most bizarre Apollo behavior… in my tests, any time I issue a query for which I have a mock, Apollo magically can’t find it.

I have 5 mocks covering queries based on a `collectionId` and some pagination variables. When I have the component under test look up ID `834940`, I get this:

```
Expected variables: {"page":1,"perPage":20,"collectionId":834940}

Failed to match 4 mocks for this query, which had the following variables:
  {"collectionId":374276,"page":1,"perPage":20}
  {"collectionId":112805,"page":1,"perPage":20}
  {"collectionId":238350,"page":1,"perPage":20}
  {"collectionId":-1,"page":1,"perPage":20}
```

Note that it says “4 mocks”. So it’s not seeing the mock I need, and the query fails. Make sense… until I change the component under test to look up ID `112805`, which you can clearly see listed in the 4 mocks Apollo ostensibly knows about.

```
Expected variables: {"page":1,"perPage":20,"collectionId":112805}

Failed to match 4 mocks for this query, which had the following variables:
  {"collectionId":374276,"page":1,"perPage":20}
  {"collectionId":834940,"page":1,"perPage":20}
  {"collectionId":238350,"page":1,"perPage":20}
  {"collectionId":-1,"page":1,"perPage":20}
```

It can still only see 4 mocks, but the mocks it can see have changed. Now, all of a sudden, `112805` is missing in the mocks it sees. And now it CAN see the mock for `834940`, the ID I queried for last time! So basically, *whatever I ask for* is the query it can’t resolve!!

Has anyone encountered this before?

---

### Context

`Collection.tsx`:

A functional component with 3 different `useQuery` calls. Only the third one is failing:

```js
import collectionQuery from './Collection.gql';

export type CollectionProps = {
  className?: string;
  collection: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  };
};

export function Collection( props: CollectionProps ) {
  /* [useQuery #1] */

  /* [useQuery #2] */

  // useQuery #3
  const {
    data, error, loading, refetch,
  } = useQuery<CollectionQuery, CollectionQueryVariables>( collectionQuery, {
    skip: variables.collectionId === -1,
    variables,
  } );

  return null;
}
```

`queryMocks.ts`:

```js
import collectionQuery from './Collection.gql';
import { CollectionQuery_collection } from '../../../graphqlTypes/CollectionQuery';

const page = 1;
const perPage = 20;

export const firstCollection: CollectionQuery_collection = {
  id: 374276,
  name: 'First Collection',
};

export const secondCollection: CollectionQuery_collection = {
  id: 834940,
  name: 'Second Collection',
};

export const thirdCollection: CollectionQuery_collection = {
  id: 112805,
  name: 'Third Collection',
}

export const fourthCollection: CollectionQuery_collection = {
  id: 238350,
  name: 'Fourth Collection',
};

export const fifthCollection: CollectionQuery_collection = {
  id: -1,
  name 'Fifth Collection (Error)',
};

export const queryMocks: MockedResponse[] = [
  {
    request: {
      query: collectionQuery,
      variables: {
        collectionId: firstCollection.id,
        page,
        perPage,
      },
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        collection: firstCollection,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    request: {
      query: collectionQuery,
      variables: {
        collectionId: secondCollection.id,
        page,
        perPage,
      },
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        collection: secondCollection,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    request: {
      query: collectionQuery,
      variables: {
        collectionId: thirdCollection.id,
        page,
        perPage,
      },
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        collection: thirdCollection,
      },
    },
  }, {
    request: {
      query: collectionQuery,
      variables: {
        collectionId: fourthCollection.id,
        page,
        perPage,
      },
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        collection: fourthCollection,
      },
    },
  }, {
    request: {
      query: collectionQuery,
      variables: {
        collectionId: fifthCollection.id,
        page,
        perPage,
      },
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        collection: fifthCollection,
      },
    },
  },
];
```

`Collection.test.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router';

import { secondCollection, queryMocks } from './queryMocks';
import { Collection } from './Collection';

it( 'Renders', () => {
  render(
    <MockedProvider mocks={ queryMocks } addTypename={ false }>
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Collection collection={ { id: secondCollection.id } } />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </MockedProvider>,
  );
} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component is fetching `collectionQuery` twice, likely due to a state change. This could be from a `useState` `set*` call, or it could be from having multiple `useQuery`s. In the latter case, when one of the 3 queries resolves (with `data` changing from `undefined` to defined),  it triggers a component re-render, which then calls the other query or queries again.

The reason why this breaks `MockedProvider` is because each mock can only be used to resolve a single query. So on the first matching API call, the mock is “spent”, reducing the `queryMocks` length from 5 to 4. Then, when the component re-renders and calls the same query again, Apollo can no longer find a matching mock. So to solve this, you have to either A.) refactor the component to only call the query once, or B.) add two of the same mock to the `queryMocks` array, like so:

`queryMocks.ts`:

```js
const secondMock = {
  request: {
    query: collectionQuery,
    variables: {
      collectionId: secondCollection.id,
      page,
      perPage,
    },
  },
  result: {
    data: {
      collection: secondCollection,
    },
  },
};

export queryMocks: MockedResponse[] = [
  /* [mockOne] */
  mockTwo,
  mockTwo,
  /* [mockThree, ..., mockFive] */
];
```